# Image in Lumia Camera App shows Grid Lumia 1020

Tags: camera, nokia-lumia-1020

I have Lumia 1020. A photo clicked from its camera comes in two resolutions, one of which is High  resolution image. It gives option to open that high resolution image in Lumia Camera App. But in my phone lumia camera App shows Grid over the image, so I cannot take screenshots or see plain image without grid.

[image: Image which has a high resolution version and it can viewed in Lumia Camera App]

and when i open this image in Lumia Camera App, it shows me Grid over the image, all the time. I tried some settings but it didn't help and the Grid never goes away.

[image: Image in Lumia Camera App with Grid]

Please let me know, what can i do or if i am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Grid is shown because you are in the "reframing" mode, meaning you can rotate and zoom in on your image and then save it - which will overwrite the original file afaik. Have you tried opening up the image from the photos app?

Comment: Yes, Thomas, I am opening the image from Photos app. The Grid is shown in Lumia Camera at the time of viewing an image and not at the time of clicking the image. When i open an image in Photos app and if it has high res version, it gives option to open it in Lumia Camera. Its when the Grid is showing.